# Blank Layout XML document in Eclipse Classic(android)

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout

I tried to edit the XML in graphical layout. When I switched to the main.xml tab I saw that the XML file is empty. To recover I need to restart Eclipse.

What can I do to prevent restarting Eclise?

Comment: did U tried with closing the xml file and open it again.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this in Eclipse as well.  Usually a ctrl-shift-F (format document) does the trick for me.  Or closing and reopening the file.